# How to use php PDO to find and replace

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I need to use PHP 7 and was advised to use PDO.  My original code looks like this...

```
 <?php 

function sentence()  {
    global $post;
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('set names "utf8"'); 
$query="SELECT name FROM seo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

//Begin find and replace
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//this is the string to look into
$myString = $row['name'];
//this is the thing to look for
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/1111/';
$patterns[1] = '/2222/';
$patterns[2] = '/3333/';
$patterns[3] = '/4444/';
$patterns[4] = '/5555/';
$patterns[5] = '/6666/';
$patterns[6] = '/1234/';
//this is what you replace it with
$result1 = $post->post_title; 
//this is the echo
echo preg_replace($patterns, $result1, $myString);

}
mysql_close();
}


?>
```

What this php code does is connect to a database, then a table "seo".  Look in the table for column named "name", select random 10 rows and where it finds the string "1111", replace it with the wordpress post title.  The output 10 random rows with the replacement for "1111" with the post title.

This worked great in PHP 5, but not so much in PHP 7.  I was told to use php PDO for PHP 7.  Here is what I have so far...

```
<?php

$hostdb   = 'localhost';
$dbname   = 'database';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$table    = 'seo';

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql  = "SELECT name FROM $table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r($result);
            //echo '</pre>';  

?>
```

How to do the actual find and replace of "1111" with the post title is a bit beyond me.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to replace something in a row, you can  the `UPDATE` query

Comment: Ok cool.  What would that look like here?  I'm very very new to programming.

Comment: Strangely, you are asking about the code which is database-irrelevant and remains essentially the same, whatever database you are using. Is it indeed *your* code posted above?